# How to auto indent and enter code from one line coding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I open jQuery script and I see one line without enter and look hard for edit
what about tool/software to view easy look thank

Comment: Most IDEs have an "auto-format" option, which applies standard indenting, etc. to your code.  Eclipse is one example.

Comment: If it's only for looking at the code, IE9's latest preview also has a formatting feature in the developer tools which will very likely also appear in the final version (so in a few months this comment will be useful ;-))

Comment: Posting a screenshot of code here makes me think of http://www.xkcd.org/763/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [JavaScript unpacker and beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).